# What is the HTML equivalent to triple quotes in Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, quote, apostrophe

If too complicated to answer, I may as well get to the problem at hand. I am trying to use an Arma XML (to do with clans in a game), and my in-game name must be entered between speech marks. However, my name itself includes speech marks.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
    <member id="76561198042696343" nick="Tate "Akzael" Atwood"> 
    <name>Vitaly Alexandrov</name> 
    <email>N/A</email> 
    <icq></icq> 
    <remark>Recruit</remark> 
</member>
```

The problem here specifically is: "Tate "Akzael" Atwood"

As you can see, the quotation marks cancel each other out. Is there a way to include the quotation marks in the name, as well as the outside ones, but have them not cancel each other out. For example, in Python you could just use: """Tate 'Akzael' Atwood""" , but I don't think it would work in this language.

NOTE: I have already tried apostrophes in the name, and it does not work with the forum's white-list, so until I can find a fix that solution is a no-go. Is it possible to maybe use apostrophes instead of quotation marks on the outside?

Comment: have you tried `&quot;`, e.g. `nick="Tate &quot;Akzael&quot; Atwood"` ?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this is XML, not HTML.

Secondly, as with Python you can just switch to single quotes:

```
<member id="76561198042696343" nick='Tate "Akzael" Atwood'>
```

or, better, escape the contents as suggested by Klaus:

```
<member id="76561198042696343" nick="Tate &quot;Akzael&quot; Atwood">
```

Comment: Ah, I was not aware (I'm quite a rookie to programming) of it not being related to HTML. Just saw <head> and assumed it was linked to HTML. Anyway, thanks, this should work. I'll tell the guys organising the XML to change it :)

Comment: @Harnell, ...if the folks building the XML were doing it right, they'd be using a parser/generator library that would take care of quoting/escaping for them, such that nothing they could do could mess it up. Better if they switched to using a tool that already knows how to do things right, rather than tuning a hand-built generator to weed out one specific corner case.